# Fuzzyfinder: any way to open multiple files at once?

Tags: vim, fuzzyfinder

I really like vim's fuzzyfinder plugin, but I often find myself wanting to open more than one file at a time (eg. every file that ends in ".py" within a directory). I can't see a way to do this in the docs, but is anyone aware of a way to do this?

Alternately, are there any other "fuzzy" file opening plugins with a comparable feature set that have this ability?

Comment: Looks like we have to implement it by ourselves. Did you see this issue https://bitbucket.org/ns9tks/vim-fuzzyfinder/issue/35/possibility-to-open-more-files-at-once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ctrlp.vim](http://kien.github.com/ctrlp.vim/) is an alternative fuzzy file finder that fully supports marking and opening those marked files.

> Use CTRL-Z to mark/unmark files and CTRL-O to open marked files.

Comment: Finally switched to Ctrl-P a year later, and really loving it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a plug-in to do this.

```
:args *.py
```

See `:help :args_f` for more information.

Comment: Thanks, that does help, but ideally I'd like to combine it with "fuzzy" filename matching. For example, to open code/my_project/{file1,file2,file3}.py, I'd like to be able to type "c<Tab>pr<Tab>*.py" and have all 3 files open. If I can't find a way to do that, args does look like a nice compromise.

Answer (score 0):

See the explanation here --> http://www.infoanda.com/resources/find.htm

```
vim `find include src -name \*.[ch] -mtime -3 -print | xargs`
```

Answer (score 0):

Fuzzy finder(fzf.vim) has it too, ctrl-t in fzf_action for example:

https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/README-VIM.md

Dunno yet why it doesn't work for the Ag/Rg options though.